# How to remove the config file of eclipse(default)

Tags: 16.04, eclipse, jdk, openjdk, rm

In my Ubuntu 16.04, I installed eclipse. But Java perspective is not working. I have installed open-jdk but Java perspective is not coming up. When I tried they are getting the java perspective by default in same way.

Then might config file removing may do the work.

So, I need to remove the config file of eclipse(default) in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: If you want to do that in order to fix the java problem, I recommend you to uninstall Eclipse completely and installing it again. Remove it using `sudo apt remove eclipse-*`, `sudo apt autoremove eclipse*`, 
`rm -r ~/.eclipse/`. And install it from the [official website](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Comment: Unless you had **manually installed** (DONT DO IT OTHERWISE) Eclipse then you should also check for the directories `/etc`, `/usr` and `/var` and locate and remove the Eclipse related files.